How to create an Elevated button with Linear gradient border
I’m trying to create an elevated button with a linear gradient border in flutter, i have used different approach, but i'm not getting desired result, please who can help me out.
I have tried creating a custom widget for the elevated button but it seems not to be working.
Here is the custom widget i created.....
class GradientElevatedButtonBorder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Color> colors;
  final double width;
  final Radius borderRadius;

  GradientElevatedButtonBorder({
    required this.colors,
    this.width = 2,
    this.borderRadius = Radius.circular(10),
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: GradientBorderPainter(
        colors: colors,
        width: width,
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GradientBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Color> colors;
  final double width;
  final Radius borderRadius;

  GradientBorderPainter({
    required this.colors,
    this.width = 2,
    this.borderRadius = Radius.circular(10),
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = width;

    final gradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: colors,
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    );

    paint.shader = gradient.createShader(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
    );

    final path = Path()
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
          borderRadius,
        ),
      );

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(GradientBorderPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

I used this class as the border property of the ElevatedButton widget:
    ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        side: BorderSide.none,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        elevation: 0,
        primary: Colors.transparent,
        shape: GradientElevatedButtonBorder(
          colors: [
            Colors.red,
            Colors.blue,
            Colors.green,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Gradient Elevated Button'),
    )

Any one with a solution to this?

I have done that @Yogi

Does this answer your question? Outlined transparent button with gradient border in flutter

No, it didn’t solve the problem at all. I have tried it out

I can offer tricky ways to get this done:

Use gradient_borders package which offers gradient borders.

 Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
               border: const GradientBoxBorder( // depend on that package to use GradientBoxBorder
                  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red]),
                  width: 3,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text('Press')),
            ),


You can freely use a Container over another to make that design:

    Container(
        width: 200,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red],
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text('Press')),
        )),

Result :

Hope it helps you.
